# Showing different elements inside nav depending on the screen/path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a few different screens in my React project. I want only one nav for all the screens and one appLayout file. But on 3 of the screens, I want `SearchField`, and on the others, I want `BackButton`. How would I achieve this?

Below is my nav code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Menu, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import './nav.css';
import { userAuthService } from '../../../services';
import { adminSelector } from '../../../reducers/admin-reducer/admin.reducer';
import { SearchField, NavIconButton, BackButton } from '../../atoms';
import { getNotificationAction } from '../../../reducers/notification-reducer/notification.actions';
import { notificationSelector } from '../../../reducers/notification-reducer/notification.reducer';
import { NotificationDropDown } from '..';

export const Nav: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [notificationAnchorEl, setNotificationAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const { userName } = useSelector(adminSelector);
  const { notifications, unseenCount } = useSelector(notificationSelector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getNotificationAction());
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleNotifyClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setNotificationAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setNotificationAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const signOut = () => {
    return userAuthService.logout().then(() => {
      history.push('/');
    });
  };

  const DropDownMenu = () => (
    <Menu
      id="simple-menu"
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      keepMounted
      open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
      onClose={handleClose}
      className="mt-12 text-black"
    >
      <MenuItem>
        <Link to="/profile" role="menuitem">
          Your Profile
        </Link>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <Link to="/settings" role="menuitem">
          Settings
        </Link>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={signOut}>Sign out</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <div className="nav-container">
      <div className="nav-bar-container">
        <SearchField placeholder="Search" searchType="Form" onChange={() => null} />
        <BackButton />
        <Button onClick={handleNotifyClick}>
          <NavIconButton count={unseenCount} />
        </Button>
        <Button
          aria-controls="simple-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={handleClick}
          className="mx-1"
        >
          <div className="text-black text-lg font-nunito">{userName}</div>
        </Button>
      </div>
      <NotificationDropDown
        notificationAnchorEl={notificationAnchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        count={unseenCount}
        notificationProps={notifications}
      />
      <DropDownMenu />
      <div className="overflow-y-auto">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to do something like this:

```
  const screenCheck = () => {
    // get url location.path() --> "/individual-user" get last section
    // const value = ""
    // if (value === location)
    // setIsLocation()
```

And then do a check to see if the search bar or back button should show:

```
  {isLocation ? (
      <SearchField placeholder="Search" searchType="Form" onChange={() => null} />
    ) : (
      <BackButton />
    )}
```

My screens that need the search field are:

- /home
- /view-users
- /organisations

The ones that need the back button are:

- /create-form
- /view-users
- /individual-users

Can anyone help me with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useLocation()` from React Router Dom to know on which path you are within your `Nav` and use a conditional to show what you want. Something like this:

```js
// at the top and outside of Nav
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
```

```js
// inside Nav outside of the JSX
const location = useLocation();
```

```js
// inside the JSX inside Nav
{["/home", "/view-users", "/organisations"].some((item) => item === location.pathname) && (
  <SearchField placeholder="Search" searchType="Form" onChange={() => null} />
)}
{["/create-form", "/view-users", "/individual-users"].some(
  (item) => item === location.pathname
) && <BackButton />}
```